# Multidimensional Arrays using values from database as Index. Outputs from localhost are different from webhost

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I asked this question just the other day:

I listened to their answers and placed the inputs in an array. I only added the arrays inside a multidimensional array so I could easily manipulate the values. I used the primary keys of the values as indexes. It all turned out according to plan. But when I placed my code in our webhost(philwebhosting), the array outputs are different. The primary key index doesn't work, instead it used the default index starting from 0-5. Now my code doesn't work anymore.

```
 <form method="POST" action="custInfo.php">
    <center><input type="submit" id="btn" name="room"></center>
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT room_name, room_type, room_rate, inclusive, description, room_status, max_cap
                                        FROM room
                                        WHERE room_status = 'available'");
        if($res = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){ 
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            if($row['available_rooms'] != 0){
                echo "<div class='chooseRoom'>";
                echo "<div class='indent'>";
                echo "<h4>".$row['room_type']."</h4>";
                echo "<h5>".$row['room_rate']."php</h5>";
                echo "<img src='../images/".$row['room_type'].".jpg' width=250 height=160>";
                /*unfinished choosing of room type*/
                echo "<h5><input type='checkbox' name='roomType[".$row['roomDetailsNo']."][]' value='".$row['roomDetailsNo']."'> Choose this Room";
                /*unfinished number of rooms*/
                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Number of Rooms:&nbsp;";
                echo "<select name='noOfRooms[".$row['roomDetailsNo']."][]'>";
                $ctr1 = 0;
                while($ctr1 <= $row['available_rooms']){
                echo "<option>";
                echo $ctr1;
                echo "</option>";
                $ctr1++;
                }
                echo "</select><br>";
                /*Number of Guests*/
                echo "<br>Number of Adult:&nbsp;";
                echo "<select name='adult[".$row['roomDetailsNo']."][]'>";
                $ctr2 = 0;
                while($ctr2 <= $row['max_cap']){
                echo "<option>";
                echo $ctr2;
                echo "</option>";
                $ctr2++;
                }
                echo "</select>";
                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Number of Children:&nbsp;";
                echo "<select name='children[".$row['roomDetailsNo']."][]'>";
                echo "<option>0</option>";
                echo "<option>1</option>";
                echo "<option>2</option>";
                echo "<option>3</option>";
                echo "<option>4</option>";
                echo "<option>5</option>";
                echo "</select><br>";
                echo "</h5>";
                echo "<table class='table'>";
                echo "<thead>";
                echo "<th>Inclusive</th><th>Description</th>";
                echo "</thead>";
                echo "<tbody>";
                echo "<td>".$row['inclusive']."</td><td>".$row['description']."</td>";
                echo "</tbody>";
                echo "<tfoot>";
                echo "<td colspan='2'>";
                echo $row['room_status'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tfoot>";
                echo "</table>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
            else{
                echo "No rooms available in the date you desire!";
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        die("ERROR: ".mysqli_error($conn));
    }

        </form>
```

I also tried to do this to the next page

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

[this is my `print_r` output in my localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOBcM.png)
[this is my `print_r` output in our localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK7RY.png)

```
    $query = ("SELECT COUNT(rooms.roomDetailsNo) AS available_rooms, roomDetails.roomDetailsNo, roomDetails.room_type, roomDetails.room_rate, rooms.room_status, roomDetails.room_pax, roomDetails.max_cap
                FROM rooms
                LEFT JOIN roomDetails
                ON roomDetails.roomDetailsNo = rooms.roomDetailsNo
                WHERE room_status = 'available'
                GROUP BY room_type;");

$adult = 0;
$children = 0;
$noOfRooms = 0;
if($res = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){ 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $adult += $_POST['adult'][$row['roomDetailsNo']][0];
        $children += $_POST['children'][$row['roomDetailsNo']][0];
        $noOfRooms += $_POST['noOfRooms'][$row['roomDetailsNo']][0];
    }
}

$_SESSION['adult'] = $adult;
$_SESSION['children'] = $children;
$_SESSION['noOfRooms'] = $noOfRooms;
```

btw, I added this code to the next page because my code was supposed to add the value of number of children and number of adults which I achieved in localhost.

Comment: Please show the generated html for the form

Comment: How can you set the $number variable with $row['roomDetailsNo'] as you don't select the roomDetailsNo from the db ?

Comment: Good catch @jiboulex

Comment: sorry. forgot to remove $number variable. it was part of my first attempt to create the code.

Comment: This is the generated form https://fbcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/v/t1.0-0/s480x480/12509716_1109361309083086_2045563735333641682_n.jpg?oh=87d529548ea6e4d48c405c76e6f2790f&oe=5708B364&__gda__=1463973480_c3e88bee9c8266ebefd72ca65459fee8

Comment: Same question, how can you use $row['roomDetailsNo'] in your select name when you don't select it in your query ?